# Catching ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS and similar errors with CreateDirectory()

Tags: c++, c

I am looking to make a program using CreateDirectory(), RemoveDirectory(), and similar functions. One of the possible return errors from these commands ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS. I want an if statement to catch this error and post a message on the screen and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `GetLastError ()` and check to see if the error condition meets `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`; after calling `CreateDirectory()` and when it returns 0.